# Format float to string two or less decimal places in objective c

Tags: objective-c

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", n]` gives me $25.01 when n is 25.011; That is what I wanted. However, what I want is when n is 25, it gives me $25 instead of $25.00. and when n is 25.1, it gives me $25.1 instead of $25.10.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Adding a zero to your format string should suffice `$%.02f`

Comment: @l'L'l No, that's the same as `$%.2f`. The `0` doesn't do anything in that position.

Comment: @l'L'l That's the whole point of the question. The OP wants the truncated results but doesn't get them with a format specifier of `%.2f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into `NSNumberFormatter`. You can specify maximum and minimum fraction digits. For example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
fmt.minimumFractionDigits = 0;
NSLog(@"12.34 = %@, 12.3 = %@, 12 = %@", [fmt stringFromNumber:@(12.34)], [fmt stringFromNumber:@(12.30)], [fmt stringFromNumber:@(12.00)]);
```

This results in the output:

> 12.34 = 12.34, 12.3 = 12.3, 12 = 12

Using that formatter, your code could be:

```
double n = 25.1;
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:@(n)]];
```

The result will be `$25.1`.